# Change the color of the bottom xaxis only

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I would like to change the bottom x-axis of my graph to blue,‍‍‍‍‍‍‍ whilst keeping the other three sides black.‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍ Is there an easy way to do this which I'm unaware of?‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible workaround is to put an empty axis on top and hide its ticks.

**Example:**

```
%Some random plot
x = 0:0.1:4*pi;
y = cos(x);
plot(x,y);

%Adjustments
ax1 = gca;                %Current axes
%Now changing x-axis color to blue
set(ax1,'XColor','b');    %or ax1.XColor='b' for  >=R2014b 
ax2=axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),... %or ax1.Position for >=R2014b
    'XAxisLocation','top','YAxisLocation','right','Color','none',...
    'XTickLabels',[] ,'YTickLabels',[],...
     'XTick', get(ax1,'XTick'));  %or ax1.XTick for >=R2014b
linkaxes([ax1 ax2]);      %for zooming and panning
```

[image: output]

**Caveat:** This changes the mode of `XTickLabels` from `auto` to `manual` and thus any zooming/panning will not automatically update the tick colors.

Comment: Thanks @SardarUsama I'll give this a go.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in newer versions of MATLAB by accessing some [undocumented features](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-axes-rulers). Specifically, you want to access the `Axle` and `MajorTickChild` properties (both storing `LineStrip` objects) of the `XRuler` property for the axes. Then you can modify the `ColorBinding` and `ColorData` properties, using the `VertexData` property to do so:

```
XColor = [0 0 1];                             % RGB triple for blue
hAxes = axes('Box', 'on', 'XColor', XColor);  % Create axes
drawnow;                                      % Give all the objects time to be created
hLines = hAxes.XRuler.Axle;                   % Get the x-axis lines
nLinePts = size(hLines.VertexData, 2)./2;     % Number of line vertices per side
hTicks = hAxes.XRuler.MajorTickChild;         % Get the x-axis ticks
nTickPts = size(hTicks.VertexData, 2)./2;     % Number of tick vertices per side
set(hLines, 'ColorBinding', 'interpolated', ...
            'ColorData', repelem(uint8([255.*XColor 255; 0 0 0 255].'), 1, nLinePts));
set(hTicks, 'ColorBinding', 'interpolated', ...
            'ColorData', repelem(uint8([255.*XColor 255; 0 0 0 255].'), 1, nTickPts));
```

And here's the plot:

[image]

**NOTE:** This should be done as a last step in updating the plot. Resizing or making other changes to the axes (specifically anything that changes x-axis tick marks) may throw warnings and not render properly since the settings above have been manually changed and therefore won't automatically update when other things do. Setting other properties to `'manual'` may help avoid this, such as [`XTickMode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e51478) and [`XTickLabelMode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e51582).

Comment: That's great thanks! Looks a bit more confusing so I'll do what you say and use this as a last step.